# How to replace sentences with an array of words postion

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a sentence like this:

```
ジェーンは先週日本に来て、毎日４時間日本語のクラスで勉強しています
```

And data token like this:

> [{"token":"ジェーン","type":"word","start_offset":0,"end_offset":4,"position":0},{"token":"は","type":"word","start_offset":4,"end_offset":5,"position":1},{"token":"先週","type":"word","start_offset":5,"end_offset":7,"position":2},{"token":"日本","type":"word","start_offset":7,"end_offset":9,"position":3},{"token":"に","type":"word","start_offset":9,"end_offset":10,"position":4},{"token":"来","type":"word","start_offset":10,"end_offset":11,"position":5},{"token":"て","type":"word","start_offset":11,"end_offset":12,"position":6},{"token":"毎日","type":"word","start_offset":13,"end_offset":15,"position":7},{"token":"４","type":"word","start_offset":15,"end_offset":16,"position":8},{"token":"時間","type":"word","start_offset":16,"end_offset":18,"position":9},{"token":"日本語","type":"word","start_offset":18,"end_offset":21,"position":10},{"token":"の","type":"word","start_offset":21,"end_offset":22,"position":11},{"token":"クラス","type":"word","start_offset":22,"end_offset":25,"position":12},{"token":"で","type":"word","start_offset":25,"end_offset":26,"position":13},{"token":"勉強","type":"word","start_offset":26,"end_offset":28,"position":14},{"token":"し","type":"word","start_offset":28,"end_offset":29,"position":15},{"token":"て","type":"word","start_offset":29,"end_offset":30,"position":16},{"token":"い","type":"word","start_offset":30,"end_offset":31,"position":17}]

how can i wrap text in sentence by start_offset and end_offset like this:

```
<span>ジェーン</span><span>は</span><span>先週</span>...
```

I've tried StringBuilder to replace at position but index of words changed, so from token 2, it's wrong.

Comment: What exactly does your data mean? It seems to contain the token *and* all the info required to find that token.

Comment: @anaximander i just want highlight sentence with tokens data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting new elements moves the position of everything *after* that element. Therefore, try starting from the end of the string and working backwards. This means you don't have to recalculate the positions, because the positions that are affected are the ones you've already dealt with.

```
string result = sentence;

foreach (var token in dataTokens.OrderByDescending(x => x.position))
{
    result = result.Insert(token.end_offset, "</span>");
    result = result.Insert(token.start_offset, "<span>");
}

return result;
```

Testing this out yields the following string:

```
 <span>ジェーン</span><span>は</span><span>先週</span><span>日本</span><span>に</span><span>来</span><span>て</span>、<span>毎日</span><span>４</span><span>時間</span><span>日本語</span><span>の</span><span>クラス</span><span>で</span><span>勉強</span><span>し</span><span>て</span><span>い</span>ます
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a new string and then do something like this (not exact code):

```
string s = null;
foreach(string token in dataTokens)
{
   s+="<span>" + token + "</span>";
}
```

**UPD:** After comments I've tried to simulate your scenario with such token:

```
 class Token
{
    private int start_offset;
    private int end_offset;
    private int position;
    string type;
    string token;

    public Token(int so, int se, int pos, string type, string token)
    {
        start_offset = so;
        end_offset = se;
        position = pos;
        this.type = type;
        this.token = token;
    }

    public string TokenProp
    {
       get { return token; }
    }
}
```

The rolling with span I've done like this:

```
List<Token> tokens = new List<Token>();

        tokens.Add(new Token(0, 4, 0, "word", "abcd"));
        tokens.Add(new Token(4, 5, 1, "word", "e"));
        tokens.Add(new Token(6, 9, 2, "word", "fgh"));
        tokens.Add(new Token(9, 11, 3, "word", "ijk"));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (Token t in tokens)
        {
            sb.Append("<span>");
            sb.Append(t.TokenProp);
            sb.Append("</span>");
        }
```

**UPD2** The answer above is way better :)

Comment: This will get horribly slow for strings of any length; string concatenation like this should use a StringBuilder.

Comment: Then he has to calculate the new position for the string builder based on the initial positions of the words + offset for <span> and </span>

Comment: yep, i have to calculate new position after each replace, but your code too simple, can't resolve my question :)

Comment: @KillerIsDead my sentence length 30, and total tokens length just 15, so if you foreach token, you can't get full sentences

Comment: Each token contains a word. You foreach through tokens, but manipulate words.